# How do you change the height of a SketchFlow ComboBox?

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-3

SketchFlow allows for the changing of the Height property for the TextBox and ListBox controls. However, I seem to be unable to change the Height property for a ComboBox. The Height property can be changed in the Properties window but it has no effect (at design or run time).

Answer (score 1):

You shuold open sketchstyles.xaml in notepad or visual studio. Then find the style for combobox-sketch. You will find 2 places(once in outermost grid definition and another in the end) of min-height in the style, set them both to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the combobox item selected in the Objects and Timeline panel?  I tried this and it works fine for me.  Are you able to resize it using the mouse and adorners?